# Geary mail not sync all massages I have for my accounts in xubuntu 16.04!

Tags: xubuntu, email, sync, geary

I'm just using geary mail with no problems! BUT I have set gmail and yahoo mail accounts and it works (I think so), the problem is that geary not sync ALL messages I have for these accounts. What I have to do in geary to refresh or sync or push ALL mails that I have for these accounts??? note: I have +- 1000 mails in yahoo account!
My system is xubuntu 16.04.thanks vladi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select `Geary > Accounts`, then for each account select `Everything` from the `Storage > Download mail` combobox.